# Вопрос в регулярных выражениях

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка 'Hello﻿World'.
Необходимо найти количество слов.
Если я записываю str.match(/\w+/g) то находит именно 2 слова.
Это хорошо но я не понимаю почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]все дело в нуль символе между Hello World
он считывается как пробел
вставьте в консоль devtool и увидете

Comment: А точнее это [Zero-Width No-Break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm) - неразрывный пробел нулевой ширины